# Force use of a base class method in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

Lets say I have two classes `Base` and `Derived`:

```
public class Base {
    public Base() { }
    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("Base: methodA");
        methodB();
    }
    public void methodB() {
        System.out.println("Base: methodB");
    }
}
public class Derived extends Base {
    public Derived() { }
    public void methodA() {
        super.methodA();
        System.out.println("Derived: methodA");
    }
    public void methodB() {
        System.out.println("Derived: methodB");
    }
}
```

Now with this:

```
Base d = new Derived();
d.methodA();
```

Will print:

```
Base: methodA
Derived: methodB
Derived: methodA
```

My question is: **Is it possible to force `d.methodA()` to use `Base.methodB()`?** I want the code to print out:

```
Base: methodA
Base: methodB
Derived: methodA
```

For those knowledgable in C++, this could be done with something like [`Base::methodB()`](http://ideone.com/7fE7NF) in the `Base` class. Is there an equivalent in Java?

I am almost sure this has been asked before, but I was unable to find anything, I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: No, an overridden method cannot be un-overrriden in Java. Calling the parent method will always call the sub-class method.  It might be possible to do this in byte code but this wouldn't be in Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a method in the base class can have an override, and the derived class has provided one, there is no way to force a call to the method of the base class.

If the base class needs to call the functionality in the base class, it can put it into a separate method, and declare it `final`. Then it could make a decision between its own implementation and the derived implementation like this:

```
public class Base {
    public Base() { }
    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("Base: methodA");
        // Call the derived method
        methodB();
        // Call the base method
        methodB_impl();
    }
    public final void methodB_impl() {
        System.out.println("Base: methodB");
    }
    public void methodB() {
        methodB_impl();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't do it.  In C++-speak, all Java methods are "virtual".  So do this instead:

```
public class Base {

    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("Base: methodA");
        baseMethodB();
    }

    public void methodB() {
        baseMethodB();
    }

    private void baseMethodB() {
        System.out.println("Base: methodB");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want by breaking out the functionality in the parent class into it's own method like so. Not the direction you were looking in but achieves what you want:

```
public class Base {
    public Base() { }
    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("Base: methodA");
        methodBInner();
    }

    public void methodB() {
        methodBInner();
    }

    private void methodBInner() {
        System.out.println("Base: methodB");        
    }
}
```